# TestNG setUpMethod() Issues

Tags: testng

I'm having issues passing different environments in individual test cases. I've tried overriding the setUpMethod() within these test cases with no luck and am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected WebDriver driver;
protected Actions actions;
protected WebDriverWait wait;
protected String url;



@BeforeMethod
@Parameters("env")
public void setUpMethod(@Optional String env){
    System.out.println("env = " + env);

    //if env variable is null use default url
    if(env==null){
        url=ConfigurationReader.getProperty("url");
    }else{
        url=ConfigurationReader.getProperty(env+"_url");
    }
    //if it is not null, choose env based on value

    driver = Driver.getDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    actions = new Actions(driver);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

    driver.get(url);

}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDownMethod(){

    driver.quit();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option of trying via a `@Parameter` is not going to scale because you cannot pass multiple parameters to multiple methods within the same class using the TestNG suite xml file.

All said and done, there are two options using which you can do this.

**Option : 1 - Annotation driven approach**

Assuming that the URL associated with a `@Test` method does not change, then we can embed this information via a custom annotation on top of the `@Test` method itself.

Here's how the sample would look like.

*Custom annotation*

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented
public @interface Environment {

  /**
   * @return - The URL to use
   */
  String url();
}
```

*Sample test class that uses the custom annotation*

```java
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AnnotationDrivenSample {

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod(ITestResult testResult) {
    String url = "http://example.org";
    Environment env = testResult.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()
        .getAnnotation(Environment.class);
    if (env != null) {
      url = env.url();
    }
    System.err.println(testResult.getMethod().getQualifiedName() + "() will use the URL : " + url);
  }

  @Test
  @Environment(url = "http://example.net")
  public void a() {
    System.err.println("A() executed");
  }

  @Test
  @Environment(url = "http://example.com")
  public void b() {
    System.err.println("B() executed");
  }
}
```

here's the output:

```
com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn66807918.AnnotationDrivenSample.a() will use the URL : http://example.net
A() executed
com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn66807918.AnnotationDrivenSample.b() will use the URL : http://example.com
B() executed

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

**Option: 2 - Annotation driven approach coupled with a data provider **

In this approach, lets say your `@Test` method is powered by a data provider and the actual URL comes from a data source which the data provider retrieves. In that case, we annotate the parameter that receives the url and then parse this.

Here's a sample:

*Custom annotation*

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Documented
/**
 * This is a marker annotation that indicates that the parameter is to be given a special treatment.
 */
public @interface UrlInfo {}
```

*Here's the sample test class*

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DataProviderDrivenSample {

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod(ITestResult testResult) {
    String url = "http://example.org";
    Parameter[] parameters = testResult.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()
        .getParameters();
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
      UrlInfo urlInfo = parameters[i].getAnnotation(UrlInfo.class);
      if (urlInfo != null) {
        url = testResult.getParameters()[i].toString();
        break;
      }
    }
    System.err.println(testResult.getMethod().getQualifiedName() + "() will use the URL : " + url);
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void testMethod(@UrlInfo String url, int anotherParameter) {
    System.err.println("testMethod is running ");
  }

  @DataProvider(name = "dp")
  public Object[][] getTestData() {
    return new Object[][]{
        {"http://example.net", 100},
        {"http://example.com", 100},
    };
  }

}
```

And here's the output

```
com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn66807918.DataProviderDrivenSample.testMethod() will use the URL : http://example.net
testMethod is running 
com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn66807918.DataProviderDrivenSample.testMethod() will use the URL : http://example.com
testMethod is running 

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so that the question gets closed?